# Using count subquery within CakePHP ORM

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

I'm looking through the CakePHP docs and I can't see anywhere that explains how you execute a subquery in the MySQL statement. I would essentially like to count the number of credits each user has as a field, but at the moment it is counting the credits cumulatively for all users into one field:

```
   $this->Users->find()
       ->contain(['Plans','Products'])
       ->contain('Credits', function ($q) {
           return $q->select(['count' => $q->func()->count('*')]);
       })->group(['Users.id']);
```

The query I'm trying to create is more like :

`SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM credits Credits WHERE Credits.user_id = Users.id) as credit_count FROM users Users group by Users.id ASC`

Comment: What type of association is `Credits`? `hasMany`?

Comment: @ndm yeah it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contained `hasMany` associations will always be retrieved in a separate query, and that is where the conditions will be applied that you are defining in the contain callback (check Sql Log tab of [**DebugKit**](https://book.cakephp.org/debugkit/3.x/en/)).

To get the results that you are looking for requires to either join in the association, and counting the `Credits` in the same query, something like this:

```
$this->Users
    ->find()
    ->select(function(\Cake\ORM\Query $q) {
        return ['count' => $q->func()->count('Credits.id')]
    })
    ->select($this->Users)
    ->contain(['Plans','Products'])
    ->leftJoinWith('Credits')
    ->group(['Users.id']);
```

or to explicitly use a subquery, which works by simply creating a regular query object, and passing it to wherever the query builder accepts expression objects, for example as the value in your select list:

```
$subquery = $this->Users->Credits
    ->find()
    ->select(function(\Cake\ORM\Query $q) {
        return ['count' => $q->func()->count('Credits.id')]
    })
    ->where(function (\Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp) {
        return $exp->equalFields('Credits.user_id', 'Users.id'):
    });

$this->Users
    ->find()
    ->select(['count' => $subquery])
    ->select($this->Users)
    ->contain(['Plans','Products']);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Selecting Specific Fields](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-specific-fields)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)**

Comment: thanks @ndm, will this also bring back User rows which do not have Credits? That's the problem I had been facing with `leftJoinWith` and `Matching`, etc... That `equalFields` looks particularly handy - thanks for that.

Comment: @Tim Both would return users without credits, yes. For the first example `innerJoinWith` should avoid that, and for the second example, you could for example use a condition utilizing the subquery results in the `HAVING` clause (which might not perform overly great when selecting large amounts of rows).